# What are the introductory mathematics courses that are most pertinent to machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, beginner, mathematics

To provide more context to this question, I have found the following list of courses in order to learn calculus:

[Course | 18.01.1x | edX](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+18.01.1x+2T2017/course/)

[Course | 18.01.2x | edX](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+18.01.2x+3T2017/course/)

[Course | 18.01.3x | edX](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+18.01.3x+2T2018/course/)

I also have found the following specialisation on coursera:

[Mathematics for Machine Learning | Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/mathematics-machine-learning)

I am wondering which of the two sets of courses is better suited to machine learning. I have already started the ones on edx but I am unsure as to whether the ones on edx are suitable as an introduction to calculus for machine learning.

Comment: There's nothing as "best" ; Check MIT OCW Calculus Courses..

Comment: @Aditya Thanks for the info. Also, I would disagree with your comment about there not being anything such as "best". I have taken multiple online courses over the past 3 years, and I assure you, certain courses are qualitatively better than others, some of them being more pertinent to a goal one is trying to achieve. Perhaps, I can rephrase my question for you, what courses are more pertinent to someone who wants a crash course in calculus given that I have previously studied calculus and want a refresher course in order to study machine learning :)

Comment: Maybe just read the lecture notes as you already know Calculus,so it won't take long enough to skim through, Check Ian Goodfellow's DL Book introduction (it has an informal introduction to Mathematical things needed), also it might help to learn things on the way :), here's one of the refresher course https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/calculus.html

Comment: @Aditya Thanks for the link and the info. This is quite helpful. Appreciate it!

Comment: Here's my favourite (By Jeremy and team) (it's a bit long but explanation is Lucid!) https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01528